# How i get last cell where user ends dragging

Tags: jquery

I am dragging on cells.
    using below code i am getting start cell text where i start dragging.
    How i get last cell text where user stop dragging.

```
var firstcell= $('td.csstdhighlight:first').text();
```

On dragging i m adding class to cell

```
$(".csstablelisttd").mousedown(function (e)
            {
                //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
                lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstdhighlight");
                e.preventDefault();
                flag = true;
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var endRow = $('td.csstdhighlight:last').parent();
                alert("lastchild" + endRow.text());
```